# Performing many get requests

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am writing a python program that uses beautifulsoup to scrape the image link off a website and then categorize the image. The website puts their images on separate pages in the given url format:
 (website.com/(a-z)(a-z)(0-9)(0-9)(0-9)(0-9)
This means the the number of url possibilities are very high (+1 million). I am afraid that if I do a get request to the site this many times, it might harm the site or put me in legal danger. How can I scrape the most amount of urls without damaging the site or putting myself in legal trouble? Please let me know if you guys would want anymore information. Thank you!

P.S. I have left a psudocode of what my code does below if that helps.

P.S.S. Sorry if the format is weird or messed up, I am posting from mobile

```
For url in urlPossibilities:
   Request.get(url)
   UrlLink = FindImgLink(url)
   Categorize(urlLink)
```

Answer (score 1):

A few options I can think of...

1) Is there a way to get a listing of these image URLs? E.g. a site map, or a page with a large list of them. This would be the preferred way as by using that listing you can then only scrape what you know to exist. Based on your question I feel this is unlikely but if you have one URL is there no way to work backwards and find more?

2) Is there a pattern to the image naming? The letters might be random but the numbers might incrementally count up. E.g. `AA0001` and `AA0002` might exist but there may be no other images for the `AA` prefix?

3) Responsible scraping - if the naming within that structure truly is random and you have no option but try all URLs till you get a hit do so responsibly. Respect robot.txt's and limit the rate of requests.